# Brixton Eureka / ConfigServer compatibility with Eureka/Config Angel clients?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

My company is using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud OSS and have many java spring-boot services reporting themselves to Eureka and getting their config overrides from the ConfigServer.  Those services are running Angel.SR3 Eureka and Config clients.  Will we have to upgrade the clients simultaneously when updating Eureka and ConfigServer to run Brixton?  Searches yield no detail on this.

Comment: have you been following the conversation here? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/978

Answer (score 0):

Reading the issue that @spencergibb posted within his comment, sure enough, some issues were found with Eureka.  The Angel client would continuously re-register itself over and over with the Brixton Eureka.  This situation is a fix for the client (which is running Angel) and will be fixed in Angel.SR7.   However, this means we have to re-release our clients to avoid the re-registration.  Having to re-deploy a new version of our clients, we might as well upgrade the client to Brixton.   The great part is that my company has upgraded 3 Eureka services (using eureka client) to Brixton with minimal impact or functional changes.   If interested in the Angel fix, it is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/978#issuecomment-219168252).

My company has also been testing with Angel config client with Brixton config server and has found no problems.  yet.